# Generating values from copula using copula package in R

Tags: r, copula

I have a bunch of questions concerning the use of the copula package in R. My overall aim is to generate synthetic values using copulas. I am analyzing a hydrological data: annual peak discharge [m³/s] and corresponding volume [m³].

I managed to apply tests on serial independence and dependence. Furthermore I identified and excluded ties and created pseudo-observations (transformation of copula values between [0,1]). Since I don’t know which copula is the best, I fitted the copula parameter first:

```
fg <- fitCopula(copula=gumbelCopula(), data=u) #  u is my data
```

I will do this for all available copulas in R. Afterwards I test the goodness of fit with the following function:

```
gofCopula(copula=gumbelCopula(fg@estimate), x=data[,2:3], N=1000, method="Sn", 
          estim.method="mpl", simulation="mult")
```

Using the “best” copula, I then want to create synthetic values. I found a function to create random samples, but I am not sure, if it does what I need.

```
random_samples <- rCopula(copula=gumbelCopula(fg@estimate), n=10000)
```

It seems to me that this function creates only random values, but is the dependency structure of my data set considered? There is also another function in the copula package `mvdc`, for the construction of multivariate distributions from copulas. What is actually the difference of `mvdc` and `rCopula`, both are generating synthetic values, aren’t they?

One last question is: Once I am able to generate my synthetic values, how can I transform them back to their real units? From reading through the documentation I understood tat I have to multiply the values for (u,v) with the inverse of their particular cdf, is this true?

---

One question is not answered yet, I want to render it more precisely: namely the function [mvdc](/questions/tagged/mvdc). According to the copula manual p. 107, it is used to *"construct multivariate distributions from copulas"*

For the function a copula family, as well as the distributions of the margins have to be specified, for instance:

> mv.NE <- mvdc(copula=gumbelCopula(fg@estimate),margins=c("norm","norm"),paramMargins=list(list(mean=0, sd = 1),list(mean=0, sd = 1)))

(here is chose a gumbelCopula and estimated the parameter with [fitcopula](/questions/tagged/fitcopula). I assume that my marginals are both distributed "normal".)

What for do I need this function? I am slightly confused because of:

- when I create random values from my copula using [rcopula](/questions/tagged/rcopula) I eventually yield "distributed" values when I pass the values of u and v respectively over to their particular distribution function (in this case both are distributed normal)
- so why is there a second option to create multivariate distributions from a copula.

I just don't get the difference...

Comment: Correct, after you sample from the copula, you transform the margins individually, in the way you suggest.

Comment: Yes, the random samples that are generated are not independent; they contain the dependence structure that results from the copula (and parameter estimate(s)) you supply. You can see they're dependent simply by plotting the result.

Comment: Just to be clear, you do not have to _multiply_ the values of (u,v) with their inverse marignal CDFs, but you have to _pass_ the values (u,v) to their inverse marginal CDFs.

Comment: `mvd` fits a multivariate copula model. `rcopula` generates simulated data with any available copula.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your answers. Indeed, when I plot the different Copulas, it seems (based on a visual comparison) that the dependence struture is depicted in the copula.

[image: Comparison of different results]

Then my next step will be to compare the different copula families in terms of looking at their goodness of fit.

@Ben: Ok, so if the distribution of one of my marginals is the generalized extreme value distribution, my u or v will be passed to the "x" of this function, since the other parameters of this distribution are fitted before. [image: forumla_gev]

Comment: You might want to interactively explore different bivariate copula families that are available in R with the shiny app [copulatheque](http://giv-graeler.uni-muenster.de:3838/copulatheque/).

Comment: You need to use the _inverse cumulative distribution function_ (CDF) also known as _quantile function_ and commonly abbreviated in R as "q" (e.q. qnorm, qgev, ...). This should be clear from Sklar's Theorem. Please pay careful attention to the theory of copulas, as it is very easy to mess around with them.

Comment: Hi Ben, sorry for the delay. Thanks for that hint! I am very glad that the GEV is already coded in R. Telling from the destribution functions on [link](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/probability.html) I thought it wasn't. I will use this one.

Comment: You will need an extra package: "evd"

Comment: @Ben thanks for linking to that app! It's incredibly helpful to visualize the copulas this way!

Comment: @Ben, could you please update the link. The link http://giv-graeler.uni-muenster.de:3838/copulatheque/ doesn't open.

Comment: The server moved and the app is now available at: [www.copulatheque.org](http://www.copulatheque.org)
Thanks for the reminder.